# Encryption and Decryption in WEP protocol

Tags: gsm, wep

What is the role of Integrity Check Value in Wireless Equivalent Privacy?
Why initialization Vector is sent as a clear message where as Integrity Check Value is sent as a cipher message?

Answer (score 1):

The role of Integrity Check Value in Wireless Equivalent Privacy is to ensure that a packet has not been modified in transit. To avoid encrypting two ciphertexts with the same key stream, an Initialization Vector (IV) is used to augment the shared secret key and produce a different RC4 key for each packet.
Source: [(In)Security of the WEP algorithm](http://www.isaac.cs.berkeley.edu/isaac/wep-faq.html)